# How to splits the long numeric into date format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, python-2.7

[![enter image description here][1]][1][![enter image description here][2]][2]

- I have data frames of 10*75 format.
- Each cell in 3rd column only contains 0123456789 and I want to splits in date format like
  0123 as days, 45 as  hours, 67 minutes and 89 seconds respectively. How to split or access numerical values at different positions?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP5BG.jpg  I have such format of column
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yagPb.jpg   I need to make like date format as shown in the output picture.

Comment: I noticed that you deleted the image.. I added numbers and datestamps from the image.. I want something similar ':London.UK.EU.StarLink.Org 317 supras supra 561 1219376117 :seconds idle, signon time'. The output will be ..... your_local_time 2008-08-21 23:35:17

Answer (score 1):

You can subset strings like this: `string[start:end:step]`

so it would be:

```
number = "0123456789"
day= number[0:4]
hour= number[4:6]
minute = number[6:8]
second= number[8:]
```

edit:

sorry dident se you used a dataframe, then the syntax is this:

```py
df['day'] = df['col'].str[0:4]
df['hour'] = df['col'].str[4:6]
df['minute'] = df['col'].str[6:8]
df['second'] = df['col'].str[8:]
```

code to show it works

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(["0123456789","0123456779","0123426789"], columns=["timestamp"])
>>> df['day'] = df['timestamp'].str[0:4]
>>> df['hour'] = df['timestamp'].str[4:6]
>>> df['minute'] = df['timestamp'].str[6:8]
>>> df['second'] = df['timestamp'].str[8:]
>>> df
    timestamp   day hour minute second
0  0123456789  0123   45     67     89
1  0123456779  0123   45     67     79
2  0123426789  0123   42     67     89
>>>
```

Comment: I know how to splits for one data but how one can do for column as I have data extration of 1000 column.

Comment: The edited part of my answer gives you this

Comment: I am not sure if its working. Can you please check?

Comment: I've added an example om a dataframe